# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1963-03-24T00:00:00.000+01:00' could not be parsed at index 19 1000

Tags: date, java-8

I get the datetime value as: `1963-03-24T00:00:00.000+01:00`

I am using Java 8 to parse the date time as following:

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX ZD");

public static ZonedDateTime parseDateTime(String date) {

    return parseDateTime(date, ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
}
public static ZonedDateTime parseDateTime(String date, DateTimeFormatter format) {
    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return ZonedDateTime.parse(date, format);
}
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
    Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1963-03-24T00:00:00.000+01:00' could not be parsed at index 19
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
```

What's wrong with my pattern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following Date Formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

instead of:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX ZD");
```

The last part of your time input is `.000+0100` which comprises of a dot, milliseconds & timezone.

The dot can be represented as it is i.e. `.`

The millis `.000` can be parsed by `.SSS`, and the timezone `+01:00` can be parsed by  `XXX`.